# Swap categories and labels highcharts (bar plots)

Tags: highcharts

I looked on SO for a solution to this problem, and after not having any luck (and much trial and error), I figured out a solution. My question is if it's the best solution, but really, I just want this to be on SO so someone else facing this problem can get a solution quickly.

In grouped bar graphs in Highcharts, data is grouped by two things: the category, and the series/label.
But sometimes it is desirable to swap what you group on - the categories or the labels.

Here's a fiddle of the solution : http://jsfiddle.net/srLtL5qd/8/

HTML:

```
<div id="container" style="width:100%; height:100%;"></div>
<div id="toggle" style="background:red; width:80px; height:40px;" onclick="toggleGrouping()">
    Click Me
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(function () {  
    $('#container').highcharts({
        credits: {
            text: 'metaflagstat.py - Charts made by Highcharts.js',
            href: 'http://ac.gt/metaflagstat'
        },
        chart: {
            type: 'bar'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Read Count Statistics'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F']
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Stuff'
            }
        },
        plotOptions: {
            column: {
                grouping: true,
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: "Series 1",
            data: [97930988, 246487056, 103547366, 160785442, 175190470, 186172354]
        }]
    });
});

    // Interesting Bit:

toggleGrouping = function() {
        newLabels = [];
        newCategories = [];
        newData = [];
        var chart = $('#container').highcharts();
        seriez = chart.series;
        $.each(chart.xAxis[0].categories, function (i, name) {
            newLabels.push(name);
        });
        $.each(seriez, function (x, serie) {
            newCategories.push(serie.name);
            $.each(serie.data, function (z, point) {
                if (newData[z] == undefined) {
                    newData[z] = [];
                }
                if (newData[z][x] == undefined) {
                    newData[z][x] = '';
                }
                newData[z][x] = point.y;
            });
        });
        while (chart.series.length > 0) {
            chart.series[0].remove(true);
        }
        chart.xAxis[0].setCategories(newCategories, false);
        $.each(newData, function (key, newSeries) {
            chart.addSeries({
                name: newLabels[key],
                data: newSeries
            }, false);
        });
        chart.redraw();
}
```

I hope someone finds it useful :)

Comment: thank you great solution. Maybe you should post this as an Q&A

Comment: Thanks man :)
What's a Q&A? :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change one word for much better performance.

(Chart will not redraw every iteration)

```
toggleGrouping = function() {
        newLabels = [];
        newCategories = [];
        newData = [];
        var chart = $('#container').highcharts();
        seriez = chart.series;
        $.each(chart.xAxis[0].categories, function (i, name) {
            newLabels.push(name);
        });
        $.each(seriez, function (x, serie) {
            newCategories.push(serie.name);
            $.each(serie.data, function (z, point) {
                if (newData[z] == undefined) {
                    newData[z] = [];
                }
                if (newData[z][x] == undefined) {
                    newData[z][x] = '';
                }
                newData[z][x] = point.y;
            });
        });
        while (chart.series.length > 0) {
            //chart.series[0].remove(true);
            chart.series[0].remove(false);
        }
        chart.xAxis[0].setCategories(newCategories, false);
        $.each(newData, function (key, newSeries) {
            chart.addSeries({
                name: newLabels[key],
                data: newSeries
            }, false);
        });
        chart.redraw();
}
```